# Linux - more efficient way to calculate price values within a file

Tags: linux, performance, awk, decimal, processing-efficiency

I have a rather large file (over 500,000 lines and about 2000 characters per line) that I need to parse through and total up the values in a specific field.

I'm currently using the following, but it's taking about 20 minutes to run:

```
grep ^D $INPUTFILE | cut -c 374-383 | paste -sd+|bc -l
```

More information on my file:
- it's a pipe delimited file
- the values may contain decimal values

I'm using RHEL.  (anyone have any ideas on a more efficient way of doing this)

SAMPLE LINE: (1 of many)

```
D|||W239337273 ||||APPLE ||ORANGES |||||||||||||||||||||00172572880|||||||||||
| | | | | |||||||||||||||||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||| 0.89| 1.95|| 1.95|||||||||||||||||||||| 0 .00||1 ||| 0.00||||||
|| 2.33|| 145.32|||||||| 0.83|||||||||||| 2.78| 37.99|||||||||||||||||||||||||
||||||||||||RAVINDERSINGH13 ||DAVID RANKIN | |19230129|01 |||STACK||2|||
|OVERFLOW ||||||||||||2076671331|046403139|1| |00||004336|||||||||||| ||||
|FISH |||||||2007878|||||COCONUTS |||CRK 0047 |||||||193264243231187998 ||||||
||30 ||| ||20191122||||1258338132 |C|||N||||||||||||||1 |||||||||6326812132 ||
|||0 | |0|||B2|||||||| |20191122|||||||||||BS1ACG962 |||THOR |CAPTAIN AMERICA
|||AVENGERS||1306885298 |||||||||||||||||||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Sorry, the above sample was modified for security and my column values were altered by mistake.  For testing purposes based on comments below, I created a sample file with 5 entries (duplicates of the sample line above) and ran the following 2 commands successfully.  Going to try to run it for the full file to check performance.

**sh-4.2$ awk -F'|' '/^D/{sum += $166} END {print sum}' sample.txt**

11.65

**sh-4.2$ grep ^D sample.txt | cut -c407-416 | paste -sd+|bc -l**

11.65

```
sh-4.2$ grep ^D full_file.txt | cut -c 374-383 | paste -sd+|bc -l
2316826.10

sh-4.2$ awk -F'|' '/^D/{sum += $153} END {print sum}' full_file.txt
2.31683e+06
```

I double checked the fields to make sure I was using the same fields in both commands:

```
sh-4.2$ cut -c 374-383 full_file.txt > test1

sh-4.2$ awk -F'|' '{print $153}' full_file.txt > test2

sh-4.2$ diff test1 test2
```

Comment: `awk` is they way to go and will do it in seconds compared to the minutes your `3-subshells` and `2-pipes` requires. If you show the first few fields of your file (something like `DRUGS|bla|blah|....` I suspect) and identify the field that `-c 374-383` represents, it should be trivial. (better - if you have a link to your input file post that)

Comment: Replace `'N'` with the actual 1-based *Field-Number* to sum: `awk -F'|' '/^D/{sum += $N} END {print "sum ", sum}' $INPUTFILE` (my best *guess* given your description)

Comment: I second David sir here, please do add your sample of Input_file and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: If post a bit of sample input and identify the field-number, I bet @RavinderSingh13 can have an efficient answer whipped out and posted in less than 60 seconds to decrease you runtime by 95%...

Comment: Not clear still, is it a single line you posted? If yes then which field we should pick up, what is the expected output, kindly do mention the same in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Hmmm... Characters 374-383 are `STACK||2|` comprising 3-fields. That's going to be kind of hard to `sum`. What number out of your input do you want to `sum`? (we can find the field-no. if you identify which number you want)

Comment: My guess is the *field-number* will be one of `128 : 0.89, 129 : 1.95, 131 : 1.95, 153 : 0.00, 155 : 1, 166 : 2.33, 168 : 145.32, 176 : 0.83, 188 : 2.78` or `189 : 37.99`. Which `field-no : value` do you need summed?

Comment: Sorry @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, I edited the post.  When making the sample data for you, I messed up the positional values.  Hope my edit makes sense.  Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: When using awk on my full file, the output appears to be too large:  2.24622e+06.

Comment: No, that shouldn't matter. `awk` can handle *floating-point* math just fine. What do you get after your 20 min. `grep | cut | paste bc`? Is it not the same? Your ` 2.24622e+06` gives an average value for the field over `500,000` records of `4.492`. Is that not reasonable given your data?

Comment: I get 2316826.10 with paste bc.... and 2.31683e+06 with the awk command.

Comment: Chuckling..... Those are the SAME NUMBER in different numeric formats `:)`.  See @RavinderSingh13 answer on how to output it without the default `e+06` format. (you can just move the decimal point 6 places to the right to get rid of the `e+06`).  How much better is the runtime `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on OP's attempts and comments.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}/^D/{sum+=$166} END{printf("%6.2f\n",sum)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}/^D/{sum+=$153} END{printf("%6.0f\n",sum)}' iInput_file

2316826

Comment: That output works, except it appears to only provide the whole number as the output and strips out anything after the decimal.

Comment: Do `awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}/^D/{sum+=$153} END{printf("%10.2f\n",sum)}'  Input_file` All of the precision is there, you just need to tell it to output it in whatever format you like? How much quicker does `awk` make the calculation?

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, Thank you sir for letting know, fixed it now.

Comment: It worked after I changed it to awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}/^D/{sum+=$153} END{printf("%.2f\n",sum)}' iInput_file

Comment: for the sample set using awk:  real    0m4.069s
user    0m3.826s
sys     0m0.234s

Comment: Roughly 1/4 the time (because you have only 1 process instead of 4 `:)`

Comment: same sample set using paste bc:  real    0m12.655s
user    0m12.404s
sys     0m1.406s

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, thank you sir for your guidance and help here :) cheers

Comment: You are welcome. Good answer. You will catch Ed and Charles soon `:)` (well, maybe not soon, it would take years for me to crawl up to that level....)

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, Thank you for your blessing to me and kind words. I honestly think you folks like my GURU, so no competition in it, I will be happy if I could touch base you guys. I really LOVE you guys for your nice attitude and knowledge(you are already in my list :) ) cheers and happy learning :)